# How to color code a cell that is labeled as a variant in VBA coding

Tags: vba, colors, variant

I have a form that the user fills out and and need to create a color coded grid based on their answer.  I can get the cell identified that needs to be colored but cannot get the color to appear properly.

```
Dim PlantName As String
Dim DateEntered As String
Dim PlantRow As Integer
Dim DateColumn As Integer
Dim Address As Variant


PlantName = Me.ComboBox1.Value
DateEntered = Me.TextBox5.Value

PlantRow = Sheets("Expedite").Range("A3:A5").Find(PlantName).row
DateColumn = Sheets("Expedite").Range("B2:BB2").Find(DateEntered).Column

Address = Cells(PlantRow, DateColumn).Address

If Me.Expedite_yes.Value = True Then
    Address.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) And Address.Text.Color = RGB(0, 225, 0)
    ElseIf Me.Expedite_yes.Value = False Then
    Address.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) And adress.Text.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

The cell found in "address should be colored green in both interior and text if me.expedite_yes.value = true but I am getting a syntax error on the address.interior.color line.

Comment: what is `Expedite_yes`?

Comment: Expedite_yes is an option button in the form the customer uses

Comment: Remove the `And` just put the two items as separate lines.

Comment: I removed the and am a still getting an error stating object required on 
Address.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

Comment: `Range(Address)...` not `Address...`

Answer (score 2):

*Main issue:* You need to modify the `Interior.Color` and `.Font.Color` of a `Range` object, not a `String` address. Also as noted in the comments, remove `And` and put the two items as separate lines.

If you were to keep your initial approach, that might look like:

```
Dim rng as Range
...
Set rng = Cells(PlantRow, DateColumn)
...
rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 225, 0)
```

*Other issues*:

1. Both `PlantRow = Sheets("Expedite").Range("A3:A5").Find...` and 
   `DateColumn = Sheets("Expedite").Range("B2:BB2").Find` assume that the `PlantName` and `DateEntered` are actually found, and will throw an error if they are *not* found.
2. You should qualify which `Worksheet` - assuming it's `Sheets("Expedite")` that the `Cells` are on. Otherwise there is an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`.

With those modifications, your code might look like this:

```
Dim PlantName As String
Dim DateEntered As String

PlantName = Me.ComboBox1.Value
DateEntered = Me.TextBox5.Value

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expedite")

Dim plantRng As Range, dateRng As Range
Set plantRng = ws.Range("A3:A5").Find(PlantName)
Set dateRng = ws.Range("B2:BB2").Find(DateEntered)

If Not plantRng Is Nothing Then
    If Not dateRng Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ws.Cells(plantRng.Row, dateRng.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found - try again!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

If Me.Expedite_yes.Value = True Then
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 225, 0)
ElseIf Me.Expedite_yes.Value = False Then
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    rng.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you define your address, variable "Address" receives the string of the address like "B2". You need to create a range object from this address string like in the code below. For the Font color I get .Font.Color working like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim addr As Variant
Dim TestBool As Boolean

addr = Cells(2, 2).Address
Debug.Print addr
TestBool = True
If TestBool = True Then
    Range(addr).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) And Range(addr).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End If

End Sub
```